# Why my aplication get stuck when i show an alert in my own "uncoughtException()" method?

Tags: android, exception, android-alertdialog

Here is my code: ("Apagar" means "Turn off", "reiniciar" means "restart")

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
{
    try
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(iAct).create();
        //alertDialog.setTitle("");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Se ah producído un error y la aplicación no puede continuar funcionando." +
                               "¿Desea reiniciarla o finalizarla?");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Reiniciar", new ReiniciarOnClickListener(iAct));
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Apagar", new ApagarOnClickListener(iAct));
        alertDialog.show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(iDefaultHandler);
        iDefaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
}
```

All the code inside `Try` block is executed, but the alert is never shown, and the screen stays grey.

In `iDefaultHandler` I saved the result of `getDefaultUncoughtException()` before seting mine.

Any information that is missing, please ask for it. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Is this running in the UI thread or in a background thread?

Comment: I never create an extra thread, so i guess it's in the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, in the debug window, when it stops in a breakpoint in this code, the suspended thread is the one that says "main".

Comment: Can you post your error trace?

Comment: As far as i understand, there is no error trace becouse the aplication never breaks. It shows a black screen and some time latter the "aplication is not responding" message comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking .create() out. Just init the AlertDialog and then show it.

Comment: You mean "out" of the Try block? I already tried without the Try/Catch block and it behaves the same way

Comment: no I mean remove it entirely. I have my AD set up without .create() and it works fine.

Comment: Ahh, i got it. Well, i realized it's not related to the alert.Now i'm working on an idea dave.c told me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `onCreateDialog` to build the dialog?  Something like:

```
private static final int DIALOG_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION = 0;

...

public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
{
    try
    {
        showDialog(DIALOG_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(iDefaultHandler);
        iDefaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("message")
            .setPositiveButton("Reiniciar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do stuff;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Apagar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do other stuff;
                }
            });
        alertDialog.create();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Obviously you can replace the default button listeners with your own if you need to.

Comment: I put that code on my activity and now my uncoughtException() method looks this way:

Comment: public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
 {
  iAct.showDialog(iAct.DIALOG_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION);
 }

But yet when i throw an exception the activity freezes.

Comment: There are a few things to try: 1) replace the `showDialog(DIALOG_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION);` call with `Log.d("uncaughtException","dialog goes here");` - does it still hang? 2) wrap your call to `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in a `try/catch` block that logs the thrown exception.  Does it change the behaviour?  3) Step through the code in the debugger, or alternatively add lots of `Log.d("TAG","message");` output to check your application behaviour.

Comment: I replaced the showDialog() for Log.d() and the log is made. But after loging it hang. The LogCat shows:
DEBUG/uncaughtException(5258): dialog goes here
DEBUG/dalvikvm(5258): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
WARN/Smack/Packet(1363): notify conn break (IOEx), close connection
DEBUG/Smack(1363): [XMPPConn] close connection, notifyClosed=false


And in the Debug Tab It shows there are binder thread #1 , binder thread #2 and thread-8, All running.

Comment: And the call to setDefaultUncoughtExceptionHandler() doesn't throw any Exception

Comment: Ok so the problem isn't the dialog, its the call to either `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` or `iDefaultHandler.uncaughtException()`.  Try suggestions 2) and 3) from my comment above.  You can also try commenting out each of the two lines in turn to find out which one causes the hang.

Comment: No, but i ereased that part of the code. Now my uncoughtExeption() just make the log, and it hang anyway

Comment: I added one more line, now it Logs and then calls Activity.finish() and it seems to work fine...

Comment: Erased which part of the code?  Both `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and `iDefaultHandler.uncaughtException()` ? If so, then I don't see how the problem is with any of the code you have provided to us...

Comment: Well, what i want to do is ask the user if he want to close the aplication or reload it when it crashes. When i catch an exception that is going to make my application crash, i can make a log or another simple things, but it freezes after all the uncoughtExeption  Method is executed. I think i'm giving up, I really apreciate your help, thank you very much! May be if you realize a way to do this it will be wellcome. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you can store the error details to the SD card, then call `startActivity(someNewActivity)`, then call `finish()`.  `startActivity()` would launch a new activity that would read the data you have saved to the SD card and ask the user if they want to send it or relaunch.